# IO.FileSystemWatcher and deleted folders

Tags: .net, filesystemwatcher

for a project of mine I need to watch a folder on the hard disk and react on any file or folder, that might be created, changed, renamed or deleted inside this folder or any of its subfolders.
To do that I created a `FileSystemWatcher` like this:

```
    Dim watcher As IO.FileSystemWatcher

    watcher = New IO.FileSystemWatcher(<path to folder to watch>)
    watcher.NotifyFilter = IO.NotifyFilters.FileName Or
                           IO.NotifyFilters.LastWrite Or
                           IO.NotifyFilters.DirectoryName Or
                           IO.NotifyFilters.Size
    watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = True

    AddHandler watcher.Created, AddressOf OnCreated
    AddHandler watcher.Changed, AddressOf OnChanged
    AddHandler watcher.Deleted, AddressOf OnDeleted
    AddHandler watcher.Renamed, AddressOf OnRenamed
    AddHandler watcher.Error, AddressOf Start.OnError

    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True
```

Apart from getting multiple change events for a single file change (I know why I do get multiple events and how to work around this), I have one major problem.

If I delete a file anywhere inside my watched folder I get a `Deleted` event for this file and I can react on it.

But if I delete a non-empty subfolder inside my watched folder I only get the `Deleted` event for the subfolder, not for the files inside this subfolder. And because the subfolder and the files inside are already deleted I can't look on the hard disk myself to figure out the deleted files to handle them.

Do you have any ideas how to be notified about the deleted files inside the subfolder?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:

I did a little more testing. When I move a subfolder inside my watched folder from on place to another, I only get the `Deleted` and `Created` for the folder, not for the included files. But in that case I at least can look directly on the hard disk for the moved files. That's not possible when deleting a subfolder.

Comment: You are not specific enough about exactly *how* you deleted the folder.  Best to assume that you see is accurate, look in the recycle bin.  And that OnRename() perhaps needs more work.

Comment: How else can one delete a folder than to select the folder and press "Delete" or "Shift"+"Delete"? And since I didn't mention "Shift" you can assume that I tried to delete the folder the oldfashioned way.
And if you read my edit, watching the recycle bin would be of no use either since one only gets the notification for the folder.